# Can anyone fix my foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have code like this

```
<?php
$array = array('http://www.google.com', 'http://www.facebook.com', 'http://www.twitter.com');
foreach ( $array as $website );
{
echo "<pre>";
echo "Hi $website\n";
echo "Hello $website\n";
echo "Welcome $website\n";
echo "</pre>";
}
?>
```

My output looks like this

```
Hi http://www.twitter.com
Hello http://www.twitter.com
Welcome http://www.twitter.com
```

I mean my code printing only the last array value. But i want output like this.

```
Hi http://www.google.com
Hello http://www.google.com
Welcome http://www.google.com
Hi http://www.facebook.com
Hello http://www.facebook.com
Welcome http://www.facebook.com
Hi http://www.twitter.com
Hello http://www.twitter.com
Welcome http://www.twitter.com
```

Can anyone tell me why its only printing last value?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon:

```
foreach ( $array as $website );
                              ^
```

Comment: Ah thanks. I didn't notice that

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
foreach ( $array as $website );
```

has an extra `;`

What happens is that you have an empty foreach, and then while `$website` is on the last item, you perform a block with an echo.

remove the `;` and you'll be fine

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon from this line:

```
 foreach ( $array as $website );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a semicolon (;) at the end of your foreach loop. This means that instead of the { } block being inside the loop, it just executes once, after the foreach loop finished iterating.

Just drop the ; from the end.

Answer (score 1):

You have a semicolon at the end of your `foreach` statement.  Remove is and you will have the functionality you require